# Place filtered constant in to a select box javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have two arrays of materials and bits. I create a constant selectedbits and filter it comparing if the properties of material are the same as well as if the property cel of bits is longer than a user input value. This should then return the bits that are available as the selectedBits. That part works. I can see when inspecting that the correct bits are being populated. But can't seem to get the selectedBit.name to print/populate the select dropdown.

The result I get is filtered as the correct number of dropdown items are showing but the values are "undefined".

< option value="undefined">undefined</option. > (modified the html so it would display here).

```
var select2 = document.getElementById('displayBits');

var materials = [
    { name: "Acrylic", metal: false, plastic: true, multipurpose: true, soft: false, hard: true },
    { name: "Aluminum", metal: true, plastic: false, multipurpose: false, soft: false, hard: true },
    { name: "Wood - Soft", metal: false, plastic: true, multipurpose: true, soft: true, hard: false },
    { name: "Wood - Hard", metal: false, plastic: true, multipurpose: true, soft: false, hard: true }
];

var bits = [
    { name: 'M1-308U', material: 'metal', ced: 3, cel: 8, flutes: 1, angle: 'up', rpm: 60000, soft: .003, hard: .005 },
    { name: 'M1-308UC', material: 'metal', ced: 3, cel: 8, flutes: 1, angle: 'up', rpm: 60000, soft: .003, hard: .005 },
    { name: 'M1-408U', material: 'mutlipurpose', ced: 4, cel: 8, flutes: 1, angle: 'up', rpm: 60000, soft: .004, hard: .006 },
    { name: 'M1-506D', material: 'wood', ced: 5, cel: 6, flutes: 1, angle: 'down', rpm: 50000, soft: .005, hard: .007 },
    { name: 'M1-506U', material: 'wood', ced: 5, cel: 6, flutes: 1, angle: 'up', rpm: 55000, soft: .005, hard: .007 }
];

if (!event.target.matches('.materialButton')) {

        const material = materials.find(item => item.name === materialValue);

        const selectedBits = bits.filter(bit => 
            (material.plastic && bit.material === 'plastic' && bit.cel >= thicknessValue) || 
        (material.metal && bit.material === 'metal' && bit.cel >= thicknessValue) || 
        (material.multipurpose && bit.material === 'multipurpose' && bit.cel >= thicknessValue)
            );
            

            for (var i = 0; i < selectedBits.length; i++) {
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.innerHTML = selectedBits.name;
                opt.value = selectedBits.name;
                select2.appendChild(opt);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `selectedBits[i].name` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo/error in this line

```
opt.innerHTML = selectedBit.name;
opt.value = selectedBits.name;
```

it should be

```
opt.innerHTML = selectedBits[i].name;
opt.value = selectedBits[i].name;
```

Comment: Sweet. I had caught the typo already but adding the [i] did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Glad your question was answered :) Welcome to Stackoverflow!!  accept the solution if it worked for you

Comment: How do I accept the solution? Nevermind, figured it out.